# Can't boot laptop from USB; error in 1 file

Tags: usb

My Windows 8.1 laptop won't recognize my USB stick, which has the Ubuntu ISO installed on it with the USB Universal Installer. My desktop, which dual-boots Windows 7 and Ubuntu, will recognize the drive as a bootable device, but when I boot from it it crashes. Performing a scan revealed that the drive has an error in 1 file, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried re-formatting the drive multiple times, no success. Any tips?

Comment: Did you check the image file itself? They can get damaged during download.

Comment: No, I already deleted it and am downloading a new one via bittorrent as suggested by the_Seppi. For future reference though, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If multiple recreations of the bootstick result in the same file error, the most likely cause is a corruption of the downloaded ISO image.

Download the image again and check for its MD5 sum (supplied at the download site)

Or even better: Download the image as torrent. The BitTorrent protocol automatically validates the downloaded data using checksums. If a block is corrupted, only this 16kB section needs to be downloaded again. This is the safest way to download any image, as long as you can trust the origin of the .torrent file.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work. Could it be a problem with my flash drive?

Comment: Which exact image do you download from where?

Comment: I downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS Desktop (64-bit) image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: You should still check the consistency of the image by computing its MD5 sum (no idea how this works on Windows...)

Comment: Okay, how do I do that?

Comment: Use Microsoft's FCIV tool: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/software-tools/ht/verify-file-integrity.htm

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't appear to be doing anything

Comment: How can I compare the checksum produced by that program with the one in the original file?